# One or more elements, at least one with given value for an attribute

Tags: php, xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I need to describe following in an XML schema: **one element must occur 1 or more times**, but **exactly one occurrence of this element must have the attribute "properties" set to value "nav"**

Example:

```
<manifest>
    <item href="example" id="02" properties="cover-image" /> <!-- optional item -->
    <item href="dummy" id="sample" properties="nav" /> <!-- mandatory item with "nav" value for "properties" attribute -->
    <item href="example" id="02" properties="mathlm scripted" /> <!-- optional item -->
</manifest>
```

My "best" try was:

```
    <xs:element name="manifest">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ><!-- at least one (item property="nav")-->
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="media-type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="fallback" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="properties" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="nav" />
              <xs:attribute name="media-overlay" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" >
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:attribute name="href" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="media-type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="fallback" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="properties" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:attribute name="media-overlay" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Bad try though, since validator gives me following error:

> local complex type: The content model is not determinist.

It's clear that this schema isn't deterministic, since the validator can't decide if he is supposed to check the encountered `item` element with the first or the second of the 2 definitions for this element...
...but how can I achieve this? Is this possible at all ?

Comment: Can you use schema 1.1? In that case, you could use assertions (`<xsd:assert>`).

Comment: @potame I can't find the answer right now but I think I can't (using `DOMDocument::schemaValidate()` in php.) I had another problem months ago (conditional child-element depending on "type" attribute of parent) and I remember the answer I found was: this will be possible when php integrates schema 1.1... I'll search further in that direction though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be achieved using XSD 1.0, it requires XSD 1.1 and assertions. I don't think your default schema validator in PHP will support XSD 1.1.

Comment: Then either I'll just drop this test, or i'll try something like a first XSLT-step transforming `item[@properties='nav']` into `item_nav`, then a second XSD-step validating this with one required `item_nav` element and x optional `item` elements... seems quite a long way for what I thought was a simple need :-(